# http_user_agent (device_os_version) is wrong

Tags: php, android, web-services, http

i ran these code and working true if i used android under 4.0 version. but when i used android v 4.2 (samsung galaxy s4) the result of device_os_version is ver 2.0 ,i think the result should ver 4.2 .can anyone tell me why ?

```
$requestingDevice = $wurflManager->getDeviceForHttpRequest($_SERVER);
$is_wireless = ($requestingDevice->getCapability('is_wireless_device') == 'true');
$device = $wurflManager->getDeviceForUserAgent($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$versi = strtoupper($device->getCapability('device_os_version'));
```

Comment: You did not mention which class you are using. In general you can see the exact android version in the user agent.

Comment: What class do i need to see the android version in the user agent

Comment: You can read the Android version in $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are using the latest version of [WURFL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wurfl/files/WURFL%20PHP/)  and then retest. If you are still having problems, you can test the User Agent on the WURFL [tools page](http://tools.scientiamobile.com/) and submit comments and device information to help correct the problem.

Remember to update your PHP API implementation if you are upgrading WURFL by reading the [docs](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/php_index.php)